# C++::global Operator Overloading Issue

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

## Scenario 1

```
enum number{num=3};
int& operator+(const int& i1,number& n2)
{
    return (i1*10 + n2);
}
int main()
{
    int a,b=7;
    number n1 = num;
    a=7+n1;
}
```

The output is program crashes with stack overflow......Why does stack overflow happen ??int& operator+(const int& i1,number& n2) ....all args and return type are reference only...then why stack overflow

## Scenario 2

```
enum number{num=3};
int operator+( int& i1,number& n2)
{
    return (i1*10 + n2);
}
int main()
{
    int a,b=7;
    number n1 = num;
    a=b+n1;
}
```

I get proper output with 73.

## Scenario 3

```
 int operator+(int i1,number n2)
    {
        return (i1*10 + n2);
    }
    int main()
    {
        int a,b=7;
        number n1 = num;
        a=b + n1;
    }
```

Scenario 3 also leads to Stack overflow
Is there copy constructor for an int object??

Comment: The first is *undefined behavior*, because you return a reference to a temporary value.

Answer (score 4):

In Scenario 1, you get a stack overflow because you are repeatedly calling the same function recursively.

```
int& operator+(const int& i1,number& n2)
{
    return (i1*10 + n2);
}//         ^^^^^
```

The marked expression creates a temporary `int`, which can bind to a `const int&`, so `operator+(const int&, number&)` is called.

Scenario 2 works because `i1*10` *cannot* bind to a non-const `int&`, so `n2` is implicitly converted to an `int` and the standard `int` addition operator is called.

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 1 is returning a *dangling reference*. The program behaviour is undefined. The stack overflow should be viewed as a manifestation of this behaviour.

Scenario 2 is well-formed as it is returning a value copy of the result. But you should change the prototype to `int operator+(const int& i1, const number& n2)` or even `int operator+(const int i1, const number n2)`, and then make adjustments to the function body to avoid the function calling itself (an anonymous temporary will bind to a constant reference); the easiest way would be to either cast the `enum` to an `int` or use the contrivance

```
return i1 * 10 - -n2;
```

although you would be back to square one if you implemented a global subtraction operator!

Comment: The above two prototypes u specified leading to stack overflow again

Comment: The prototypes u specified resulting to stack overflow...please let me know if you need details

Comment: Did you adopt my "contrivance" or the cast of the enum?

Comment: I did not use contrivance" or the cast of the enum but I changed the function prototype and checked which results in stack overflow